# Sentence formation perfectly

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Bring here the book which your father brought from Delhi yesterday.

Is that the above sentence correct grametically. The position of "here" above is valid or not. That was the my concern.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatically valid. What made you think it might *not* be?

Comment: Fumble,. The position of "here" above is valid or not. That was the my concern.

Comment: Imperative: Bring the book here that etc. NOT: bring here the book in this case. I'm sorry but I have never used; Bring here the book like that.

Comment: It's correct, but sounds highly formal, pretentious, or archaic.

Comment: @Hussain: I see. So what you *should* have asked was "Does this sentence sound *natural*?", not "Is it *grammatically valid*?" As I said before, it's valid - but it's just not something a native speaker would say. As James K says below, we'd rephrase to avoid that massively distracting diversionary element between the verb+object ("bring"+"the book") and the adverb ("here").

Answer (score 3):

While understandable, the placement of "here" is unusual.

It is grammatically well formed. However a major rephrasing might make it more natural.

> Your father brought a book from Delhi yesterday. Please bring it here.

The usual structure is "Bring X here". I know why you want to move the word "here"; the normal structure gives:

> Bring the book, which your father brought from Delhi yesterday, here.

The very long noun phrase "the book ... yesterday" makes this sentence hard to parse. It breaks the "end weight rule". But just moving the word "here" is less than ideal, which is why I've suggested rephrasing.